# Testing PUT operation on swagger, I got PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: java, sql, rest, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

```
[UPDATE AR.BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DTLS SET KEY_NM = ?, KEY_VAL = ?, KEY_DESC = ?, LAST_UPDT_USER_CD = ?, LAST_UPDT_DTM = CURRENT TIMESTAMP WHERE  BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DTLS_ID = ? && BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID = ? ];
```

```
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10145][10844][3.69.66] Invalid parameter 7: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

`BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_DTLS_ID` IS PK and `BATCH_JOB_CONFIG_ID` is FK to the table. Both are type `Long`. can you see the issue?

Comment: You only have six placeholders (`?`) in the statement. Usually they're numbered starting with 1 (I don't know why it's not 0). So there would be no 7, just 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6..

Comment: Where should the 7th placeholder be placed?

Comment: Why do you need one? Placeholders are driven by the SQL, not the other way around. Your SQL looks complete and only needs six values put in it, so unless the SQL is wrong, you only need to supply six values to substitute in for the placeholders.

Comment: I'm sending this [ { "batchJobConfigDtlsId": 600, "batchJobConfigId": 0, "keyNm": "fff", "keyVal": "striwwwng", "keyDesc": "sss", "lastUpdtUserCd" : "ddd" } ]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the '&&' keyword after the WHERE clause. It should be 'AND'.